# Its compiling but idk why its telling me "core dumped" when ran

Tags: c++

I am trying out the first part of my code, I am trying to eliminate all numbers up to the inputted number that are divisible by 2 without using (vector, division, or modulus)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int num;  
int array [num];
cout << "Please enter a number" << endl; 
cin >> num; 
cout << endl; 
if(num == 0)
{
    return 0;
}
int var = 2; 
int check;
for(int x = 0; x < num;x++)
{

    array[x] = var; 
    check = var; 
    while(check > 0) // This loop checks if a number is divisible by 2
    {
    check = var - 2; 
    }
    if(check == 0)
    {
        array[x] = 0; 
    }
    else
    {
    cout << array[x]; 
    }
    var++;
}
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? `int array [num];` is not valid C++ code.

Comment: Notice what value `num` is when you make the array, too. Using uninitialized variables is bad.

Comment: This is what debuggers are for :/

Comment: int array [num] worked before I made additions to the code. Are you sure this is the problem? Im using the site compilr.com

Comment: Ok I put the cout before the declaration of the array and that helped. Now it wont output anything from the loop I created.

Comment: Lol awk, it was because I was doing check = var - 2 instead of check = check - 2.

Answer (score 2):

```
int array [num];
```

This should ideally generate a compiler warning which should look something like:

> ISO C++ forbids variable-size array

Note that the above line from your code doesn't necessarily lands you into undefined behavior territory. You are in the **implementation defined territory** .
Now as to why your code is failing it's because num in uninitialized. This is undefined behavior. So no surprises that your code is showing random behavior.
Moving the definition of the array below the point where you are inputting num will work.
Although if you truly want a variable sized array want your code to be portable across compilers, allocate it on heap.

```
cin >> num;
int *array = new int[num]; // don't forget to delete this, or even better use unique_ptr
```

Better would have been std::vector but then the question puts an artificial restriction on its usage. 
Also please rename the `array` variable to something else. c++11 has a standard container with the same name.

Comment: i would say `std::vector<int> array = std::vector(num)` is better than an array, or array wrapped in unique_ptr;

Comment: @SingleNegationElimination Even I feel so. But then the OP has an artifical restriction  without using (vector, division, or modulus) Modified my answer to mention your point explicitely